# Unable to edit remarks on a Documentation topic

Tags: bug, documentation-topics

I am trying to add a documentation topic to the Ruby on Rails tag. However, in the bottom pane, the site lets me edit the Examples section but not the Introduction section or the Remarks section. Can this be fixed?

[image]

To be more clear, when I click on the Introduction (or) Remarks link, nothing happens. I am using Chrome on Mac.